# Questions about understanding networks (Telecommunications eng)

Tags: network, telecommunications

So I read about Network topology, about typs of communications like ptp, ptmp, mptmp and about Addressing methods (multicasting, broadcasting), etc...

I'm very confused. What is the difference between ptmp and broadcasting? Aren't they the same?
And if we look on a linear daisy chain network, it's seems like using ptp for moving the information from one node to another, however, when you think about it - its actually ptmp (because more than one node gets the information...)
And what are the **real** difference between logical topology and physical topology - can you give me an example where they are not the same?

(I've started to read about it because I was intersted about the networks of swarms of drones, so examples in relation to this topic would help me understand better)

Sorry about my bad english and thanks!

Comment: It has little to do with electronics or electrical engineering, perhaps some other stackexchange site would be more suitable for this question?

Comment: one-to-many is simply not the same as one-to-everyone, and when we talk about broadcast, we typically have fixed transmitter and receiver roles.

Comment: `What is the difference between ptmp and broadcasting?` is like asking `What is the difference between fruit and oranges?` ..... broadcasting is ptmp, so is multicasting

Comment: @jsotola - not sure which is the fruit and which is the orange...

Comment: @Justme - can you mention the right place to ask this?

Comment: the two sentences have exactly equivalent wording ... investigate broadcasting and multicasting

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between ptmp and broadcasting?

- PTMP is point-to-multipoint, where each recipient address is explicitely given, or otherwise configured.
- Between the two is multicasting, where the recipient is denoted by a group address instead of a single node address.
- Broadcasting is where the recipients are unlimited: anyone who hears the message will receive it.

If PTMP is implemented at the physical layer, e.g. a central radio station and 5 known endpoint nodes, then broadcast isn't physically any different from PTMP. The fundamental difference is that the central node knows about each receiver in advance, and expects those receivers to act on the data. In broadcasting, such close-knit relationship is not expected. That's the primary difference.

> What are the real difference between logical topology and physical topology - can you give me an example where they are not the same?

You simply choose both topologies not to be the same. You can choose whichever ones you want, they are completely decoupled from each other.

Example:

- Physical topology: star. Think an Ethernet switch with endpoints attached via twisted pair.
- Logical topology: ring. Think token passing.

A node receives a token with some data, removes the data destined for itself, appends data it wants to send out, and sends the token to the next device in the ring.

This token - actually an Ethernet packet - goes to the switch, gets forwarded to the port of the recipient, and then the recipient node does the same thing. Of course some node must first inject the token into this logical ring - that's done in the ring establishment/recovery process.

The way people typically talk of token ring assumes that *both* the physical and logical topologies are that of a token ring. That's not necessary at all. You can run token ring on top of modern internet, where many different physical and logical architectures all **inter**-operate. E.g. the internet connections may go via packet relay, frame relay (ATM), PTMP (cellular network), or whatever else you may think up.

Any particular mix of a logical and physical topology may not be the best performing, but that's not the point. Right now you're learning the *jargon* of network topologies. Choosing the best mix of physical and logical topologies is the *design* or *synthesis* aspect. You need to know the jargon first.

For example, for token passing to be efficient, it takes certain characteristics of the physical layer. A star-shaped switched packet network will have better throughput with immediate forwarding on the switch, right after the header is decoded, instead of a typical store-and-forward. Even faster would be a physical ring, where each node has two ethernet ports, and a point-to-point connection between successive nodes in the ring. And so on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but can you please give a much more simple and easy-to-understand example of 2 different layers of physical and logical topologies? still not sure I understand...